Fodor's central systems in computability terms
According to Fodor, the mind is comprised of both peripheral systems that are modular (and thus can be computed), and central systems which are not modular (and thus cannot be computed).
On the contrary, the massive modularity theory claims that even the central systems can be modular and computed.
I've been trying to think of this subject in Turing's terms, most specifically in the notion of computable functions. Turing famously presented the argument for non-computable function such as the halting problem.
My question is, was (/is) there any mathematical argument for a central system that attempts to postulate it as a computable function, or disprove its computability (on Fodor's side)?

Could you please explain a bit Fodor's conception of the working brain as far it relates to your question. And indicate which two systems in the mind are meant. In which sense is "modular" meant, and why is the operating of a modular brain system non "computable". Thanks.

@JoWehler Fodor has two concepts in relation to the modularity of the brain - peripheral systems and central systems. For Fodor, the peripheral systems are modular and get be investigated in cognitive science (because they're information-enclosed). Central systems (e.g. high-level thinking, long-term planning), on the other hand, are not information-enclosed, and thus cannot be investigated because they are not modular (and cannot be). Modular means can be further divided, to smaller systems.

(this is most probably only a subset of his philosophy and when I say "has two concepts" I mean in relevance to my question)

See for example in SEP - "central systems, such as systems involved in belief fixation and practical reasoning, are not modular."
